# Conditions on Stage template not working in Azure yml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have below main YML pipeline

[image]

And below is the template that is being called.

[image]

When trying to run the main pipeline is showing the error per below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej.

When you add condition to the stages level, you need to make sure that there is at least one stage that meets the condition at all times.

In addition to adding an empty stage, you could also add the negative condition in the Yaml sample:

For example:

```
stages:
- ${{if eq(variables['envName'],'sbx')}}:
  - template: test.yml
    parameters:
     buildSteps: test
- ${{if ne(variables['envName'],'sbx')}}:
  - stage: Test
    jobs:
    - job: TestJob
      steps:
        - script: echo Test
          displayName: 'Test Stage'
```

In this case, if the `envName = sbx`, it will run the template, or it will run another stage.

Comment: Thanks yeah.. my condition was false... sorry couldnt get earlier.

Comment: @sharadjain Yes. This is the root cause of this issue.  In this case, you need to add another stage to ensure that there is a valid value under the Stages level. Glad to know that this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your condition is not met. So `envname` is not `sbx` and thus your template is skipped, and you can't run pipeline without any stage. Please make sure you have always at least one stage regardless of the result of the condition, or sth like empty stage for non `sbx` env.

Comment: Thanks yeah.. my condition was false... sorry couldnt get earlier.

Comment: Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?